# How to use asynchronous Python with Google Cloud Spanner?

Tags: python, asynchronous, fastapi, google-cloud-spanner

It's not clear [from the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/spanner/latest/google.cloud.spanner_v1.services.spanner.SpannerAsyncClient#google_cloud_spanner_v1_services_spanner_SpannerAsyncClient_execute_sql) how to set instance and database name when configure an async spanner client.
Does anybody know what is the best way to work with Spanner from async Python.

I use FastAPI and a basic request with a simple SQL fails with

```
  File "/Users/annas/python_virutal_envs/spanner-exp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers_async.py", line 84, in __await__
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(rpc_error) from rpc_error
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Invalid ExecuteSql request. [field_violations {
  field: "session"
  description: "Expected projects/{project ID}/instances/{instance ID}/databases/{database name}/sessions/{session ID}\nGot: session_value\nError: projects/{project ID} is missing from uri."
}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the client that you are trying to use is the low-level gRPC client. That means that you will have to understand how the [Cloud Spanner gRPC interface](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rpc/google.spanner.v1) works.

Regarding the specific question:

1. The database name is part of the session name. In order to use the `ExecuteSql` method, you first need to create a session by executing [CreateSession](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rpc/google.spanner.v1#google.spanner.v1.Spanner.CreateSession) or [BatchCreateSessions](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rpc/google.spanner.v1#google.spanner.v1.Spanner.BatchCreateSessions). That will create one or more sessions that you can then use with subsequent `ExecuteSql` method.
2. The `session` field of `ExecuteSqlRequest` must include the **full name** of the session. That takes the form `projects/my-project/instances/my-instance/databases/my-database/sessions/my-session`. The session name must be an existing session (i.e. one that was returned by a `CreateSession` call.